# Neo4J OGM MappingException: Field with primary id is null for EMF class

Tags: java, neo4j-ogm, eclipse-emf

I constructed an EMF model that should dictate the types of entities that are allowed to be stored in a Neo4J database instance.

I then wanted to annotate the EMF model classes with Neo4J OGM (version 3.2.28) to keep the connection to Neo4J as easy as possible.

It looks something like this:

[image: Example EMF model]

`BaseElement` and `ToolNameArtefact` are abstract. The field `uuid` in `BaseElementImpl` is annotated with `org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id`.

Now, when I try to store an instance of `ConcreteArtefact` via *Session#save()*, I get the following error message:

> org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Field with primary id is null for entity foo.bar.ConcreteArtefact@64d43929 (uuid: 7745782f-2c61-4450-985a-8cf2986afa49, projectName: )
> at org.neo4j.ogm.context.MappingContext.nativeId(MappingContext.java:556)
> at org.neo4j.ogm.cypher.compiler.CypherContext.getIdentity(CypherContext.java:66)
> at org.neo4j.ogm.cypher.compiler.CypherContext.visitedNode(CypherContext.java:90)
> at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:267)
> at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:170)
> at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.lambda$save$1(SaveDelegate.java:89)
> at java.util.Collections$SingletonList.forEach(Collections.java:4822)
> at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:89)
> at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:479)

Although the `uuid` field is clearly set.

### Other solution proposals

My package names are all [lower-case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027288/8383428).

Moving the `NodeEntity` [annotations to the interfaces instead of the implementing classes](https://community.neo4j.com/t/using-ogm-with-nodeentity-label-on-interface/1294) did not help.

The classes in question have a [no-arg constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37825770/8383428).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was a problem with Neo4J OGM itself. A developer answered in [this thread](https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-ogm-mappingexception-field-with-primary-id-is-null-for-emf-class/50700/6), that the issue will be fixed in future versions (starting from `3.2.29`)